# Can't update data in SQL table from auto populated form in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, materialize

**Hi I'm trying to get my SQL database to update with user input via my HTML form that was displayed from my javascript file. Help is very appreciated :)**

*index.html*

Display Events (HTML)

```
<!---- My Events ---->
       <div id="my_events" class="menu_link">
           <br>
           <nav class="clean">
               <div class="nav-wrapper">
                   <div class="col s12">
                       <a href="#home" class="breadcrumb" onclick="hideAll(); loadPage()">Home</a>
                       <a href="#!" class="breadcrumb blue-text accent-3">My Events</a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </nav>
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col s12">
                   <h4>My Events</h4>
                   <button onclick="displayEvents(); loadPage()" class="waves-effect waves-light btn indigo">Display
                       Events</button>
                   <!-- Preloader -->
                   <div class="loadprogress indigo darken-4" style="width: 100%">
                       <div class="runningbar indigo lighten-1"></div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="content">
                       <!-- Table container -->
                       <table>
                           <!-- <th>Event ID</th> -->
                           <th>Event ID</th>
                           <th>Event Name</th>
                           <th>Event Description</th>
                           <th>Event Category</th>
                           <th>Event Address</th>
                           <th>Event Location</th>
                           <th>Event Date</th>
                           <th>Event Time</th>
                           <table id="eventsTable" class="striped">
                               <!-- List user events -->
                           </table>
                       </table>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
```

Update Events Modal (HTML)

```
   <!---- Update Event Section ---->
        <!-- Modal Structure -->
        <div id="update_events" class="modal">
            <h5 class="modal-close right" onclick="closeModal()">&#10005;</h5>
            <div class="modal-content">
        
            </div>
        </div>
```

*script.js*

Display Events Fetch (JavaScript)

```
/* - Display Events - */
function displayEvents() {
  loadPage();
  // Define output string that will display the database data
  var outStr = '';
  var outStr2 = '';
  fetch('api/ws.php?action=displayEvents', {
    method: "GET",
    credentials: "include",
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      loadPage();
      response.json().then(function (data) {
        localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(data));
        // console.log(data);
        data.forEach(row => {
          outStr +=
            '<tr><td>' + row.eventID +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventName +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventDescription +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventCategory +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventAddress +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventLocation +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventDate +
            '</td><td>' + row.eventTime +
            '</td><td><button href="#update_events" class="modal-trigger" onclick="fillUpdate(' + row.eventID + ')" value="' + row.eventID + '"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></button>' +
            '</td><td>' + '<button onclick="deleteRemoveEvent(' + row.eventID + ')" value="' + row.eventID + '"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></button>' +
            '</td></tr>';
          outStr2 =
            `<div>
              <h4>Update Events</h4>
                <form action="api/ws.php" method="POST" onclick="return preventDefault()" novalidate>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">title</i>
                        <input id="update_ev_name" name="update_ev_name" placeholder="Event Name" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">notes</i>
                        <textarea id="update_ev_desc" name="update_ev_desc" class="materialize-textarea"
                            placeholder="Event Description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">category</i>
                        <input type="text" id="update_ev_cat" name="update_ev_cat" placeholder="Enter Your Event Type">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">map</i>
                        <input type="text" id="update_ev_address" name="update_ev_address" placeholder="Enter Your Address">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">flag</i>
                        <input type="text" id="update_ev_loc" name="update_ev_loc" placeholder="Event Location">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">date_range</i>
                        <input type="text" id="update_ev_date" class="datepicker" placeholder="Event Date">
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s6">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">schedule</i>
                        <input type="text" id="update_ev_time" class="timepicker" placeholder="Event Time">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="eventid" value="`+ row.eventID +`" id="eventid">
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" id="updateEvent">
                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" onclick="postUpdateEvent(`+ row.eventID +`)">Update
                        Event</button>
                </form>
            </div>`
        });
        document.getElementById('eventsTable').innerHTML = outStr;
        document.getElementById('update_events').innerHTML = outStr2;
      });
    });
}
```

Autofill Update Form (JavaScript)

```
/* - Autofill Update Form - */
function fillUpdate(eventid) {
  console.log("Fill event with id " + eventid);

  events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));
  // console.log(events);

  selectedEvent = events.filter(event => event[0] == eventid)[0];

  if (selectedEvent != null) {
    console.log(selectedEvent);
    document.getElementById("update_ev_name").value = selectedEvent[1];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_desc").value = selectedEvent[2];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_cat").value = selectedEvent[3];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_address").value = selectedEvent[4];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_loc").value = selectedEvent[5];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_date").value = selectedEvent[6];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_time").value = selectedEvent[7];
    // document.getElementById("eventid").value = selectedEvent[8];
  }
}
```

Update Events Function with Fetch (JavaScript)

```
/* - Update Events - */
function postUpdateEvent(eventid) {
  console.log("Update event with id " + eventid);

  events = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));

  selectedEvent = events.filter(event => event[0] == eventid)[0];

  var eventid = "eventid";

  if (selectedEvent != null) {
    console.log(selectedEvent);
    document.getElementById("update_ev_name").value = selectedEvent[1];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_desc").value = selectedEvent[2];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_cat").value = selectedEvent[3];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_address").value = selectedEvent[4];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_loc").value = selectedEvent[5];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_date").value = selectedEvent[6];
    document.getElementById("update_ev_time").value = selectedEvent[7];
    // document.getElementById("eventid").value = selectedEvent[8];
  }

  var userUpdate = {
    'update_ev_name': document.getElementById("update_ev_name").value,
    'update_ev_desc': document.getElementById("update_ev_desc").value,
    'update_ev_cat': document.getElementById("update_ev_cat").value,
    'update_ev_address': document.getElementById("update_ev_address").value,
    'update_ev_loc': document.getElementById("update_ev_loc").value,
    'update_ev_date': document.getElementById("update_ev_date").value,
    'update_ev_time': document.getElementById("update_ev_time").value
  }

  // var updatefd = new FormData();
  // updatefd.append('action', 'update');
  // updatefd.append('eventid', eventid.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_name', update_ev_name.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_desc', update_ev_desc.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_cat', update_ev_cat.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_address', update_ev_address.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_loc', update_ev_loc.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_date', update_ev_date.value);
  // updatefd.append('update_ev_time', update_ev_time.value);
  // updatefd.append('updateEvent', updateEvent.value);
  fetch('api/ws.php?action=updateEvent', {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(userUpdate),
    credentials: 'include',
    // body: updatefd,
  })
    // Force error into console
    .then(function (response) {
      response.text().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
      });
      // HTTP Response Codes
      if (response.status === 200) {
        // loadPage();
        console.log(eventid.value);
      }
      if (response.status === 202) {
        console.log('Update Successful');
      }
      if (response.status === 400) {
        errormessage('Error: Bad Request');
        console.log('Bad Request');
        console.log(eventid.value);
        return;
      }
      if (response.status === 401) {
        console.log('Not permitted');
        return;
      }
      if (response.status === 501) {
        errormessage('Error: Not implemented');
        console.log('Not implemented :(');
        return;
      }
      response.text().then(function (text) {
        console.log(text);
      });
    });
}
```

*ws.php*

Switch Case API (PHP)

```
   /* - Display User Events - */
        case "displayEvents":
            // if ($_SESSION['se']->is_logged_in()) {
            $result = $db->displayEvents();
            if ($result == false) {
                http_response_code(501);
            } else {
                http_response_code(202);
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
            // } else {
            //     http_response_code(401);
            // }
            break;
            /* - Autofill the update form - */
        case "fillUpdate":
            if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
                $result = $_SESSION['se']->is_logged_in();
                if ($result == true) {
                    $evid = $_POST['evid'];
                    $details = $db->get_details($evid);
                    if ($details == false) {
                        http_response_code(501);
                    } else {
                        http_response_code(201);
                        echo json_encode($details);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
            /* - Update the User Event - */
        case "updateEvent":
            if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
                // $evid = $_GET['evid'];
                $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';
                $objreg = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
                $evid = testInput($objreg['evid']);
                $update_ev_name = testInput($objreg['update_ev_name']);
                $update_ev_desc = testInput($objreg['update_ev_desc']);
                $update_ev_cat = testInput($objreg['update_ev_cat']);
                $update_ev_address = testInput($objreg['update_ev_address']);
                $update_ev_loc = testInput($objreg['update_ev_loc']);
                $update_ev_date = testInput($objreg['update_ev_date']);
                $update_ev_time = testInput($objreg['update_ev_time']);
                $db->updateEvent($evid, $update_ev_name, $update_ev_desc, $update_ev_cat, $update_ev_address, $update_ev_loc, $update_ev_date, $update_ev_time);
                // echo "Record updated successfully";
                http_response_code(202);
            } else {
                http_response_code(400);
            }
            // if ($_POST["eventid"] == null)
            break;
```

*db.php*

Database Functions (PHP + SQL)

```
/* -- Display Events Function -- */
    function displayEvents()
    {
        db_connection();
        try {
            $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare('SELECT eventID, eventName, eventDescription, eventCategory, eventAddress, eventLocation, eventDate, eventTime FROM events');
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            throw $ex;
        }
    }
 /* - Autofill the Update Event Form - */
    function get_details($evid)
    {
        $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM events WHERE eventID = :eid");
        $stmt->bindValue(":eid", $evid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch();
        return $result;
    }

    /* -- Update Events Function -- */
    public function updateEvent($evid, $update_ev_name, $update_ev_desc, $update_ev_cat, $update_ev_address, $update_ev_loc, $update_ev_date, $update_ev_time)
    {
        print_r("hello");
        db_connection();
        try {
            $this->dbconn->beginTransaction();
            /* --- Event Table --- */
            $stmt = $this->dbconn->prepare("UPDATE events SET eventName = :update_ev_name, eventDescription = :update_ev_desc, eventCategory = :update_ev_cat, eventAddress = :update_ev_address, eventLocation = :update_ev_loc, eventDate = :update_ev_date, eventTime = :update_ev_time WHERE eventID = :eid");
            // bind values
            $stmt->bindValue(":eid", $evid);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_name', $update_ev_name);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_desc', $update_ev_desc);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_cat', $update_ev_cat);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_address', $update_ev_address);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_loc', $update_ev_loc);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_date', $update_ev_date);
            $stmt->bindValue(':update_ev_time', $update_ev_time);
            // Execute the update statement
            $stmt->execute();

            // Commit changes here 
            $this->dbconn->commit();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $ex->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Errors I'm getting :( and no respose/preview errors in network tab
[image]

Comment: Hello! What is the expected behavior and what are you experiencing instead? Are there any errors? Have you been able to narrow down the problem to a specific part of the stack?

Comment: I just added a screen shot above to the question :) Mostly undefined errors